# androidplot zoom not working properly on all the devices

Tags: android, zooming, androidplot

I am using line chart of androidplot library to show the statistics.

**Problem:** zoom functionality is working fine in high configuration devices but  not working on samsung s4 and moto e.as i have tested.

**Steps to produce the issue :** extreme zoom on the chart then zoom out slowly.

**Result :** only the values/labels are moving disconnected to the series line. refer the image.

Any help would be appreciated ..

[image]

Comment: how are you engaging the zoom behavior?  are you extending XYPlotZoomPan?

Comment: Here is the demo activity where i just added some static data.
https://gist.github.com/Gurpreet258/3d6195250794a2c79e113239f4a151b9

Comment: Hi Nick, did you get the idea of the issue.? after extreme zoom when we zoom out slowly towards one side.. some value/labels starts moving disconnected to the graph line. any solution for the same ? this is reproducible with androidplot demo app.